# Using variable as NSTimer intervals

Tags: swift, xcode6

when i try to use integer variable as a timer interval in NSTimer in swift i get " extra argument "selector in call"
this is the code :

```
var count = 3
var Timer = NSTimer()


@IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(count, target: self, selector: Selector("result"),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

if i put 3 instead of count it works perfectly 
i want to be able to give the user the advantage to set the interval himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval takes a Double for that first parameter. Try using:

```
var count: Double = 3.0
```